# ASP.NET MVC Identity:how do I Extend AspNetUserRoles table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

In ASP.NET MVC Identity,the relations data for Users and Roles is saved in AspNetUserRoles table, this table has two field:UserId,RoleId, but i want to add other fields to this table, such as department field.

So if an user logins in different departments,he will have different roles. 
Anyone knows how to do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you add a column to **AspNetUserRoles** table, it will require a lot of infrastructure changes including filters. Easiest way is to add roles with **Department - Role Name**. For example, *HR Department - Manager*.

Comment: or create your own table with UserId RoleId DepartmentId

Comment: Not sure how to model the 3 keys table using EF Code first. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you found any solution how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

I Would Suggest you investigate ASPNet User Claims. You can assign different claims to a user with the identity manager, and based on the claim type of the user you will allow him access or not. Create a custom Claims Attribute which will be placed on top of the various controller to authenticate the user. this must be implemented based on your needs. the custom attribute will then fire before the controller gets executed and if the uses is allowed he will pass. else return to error page of you choice.

Sample Attribute usage

```
[ClaimsAuthorize(ClaimsData.EditAddress)]
    public ActionResult CitiesPartial()
```

Attribute Authentication

```
 public class ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private readonly string _claimType;
    public ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute(string type)
    {
        _claimType = type;
    }
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var user = (ClaimsPrincipal)HttpContext.Current.User;

        if (user.HasClaim(_claimType, "True"))
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }
        else
        {
            HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext, _claimType + " Not Allowed ");
        }
    }

    protected void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext, string message)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                                   new RouteValueDictionary 
                               {
                                   { "action", "ClaimNotAuthorized" },
                                   { "controller", "Home" },
                                   {"errorMessage", message }
                               });
    }

    public static bool AuthorizedFor(string claimType)
    {
        var user = (ClaimsPrincipal)HttpContext.Current.User;
        return user.HasClaim(claimType, "True");
    }
}
```

hope this helps.